# Wrong TestConfig gets used in Spring boot integration test

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I have a certain test case with mocked bean configuration:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {StockTraderApplication.class, ILiveOrderHandlerImplTest.TestConfig.class},
properties = {"unit_test_no_external_services=true"})
class ILiveOrderHandlerImplTest {
  @TestConfiguration
  public static class TestConfig {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisherBean() {
      return Mockito.mock(ApplicationEventPublisher.class);
    }
  }
```

I also have a different test class

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = StockTraderApplication.class)
class StockTraderServiceIntegrationTest {
```

In this test class I want real event listeners to get invoked. However when I run a test from this class it is using the mocked ApplicationEventPublisher from the first class. Why does this happen?

Comment: Picked up by component scanning and used.

Comment: But in the 2nd test I didn't specify the TestConfiguration.

Comment: It still is in the classpath and thus picked up by the compoent scan. Like other configuration classes.

Comment: I'm confused. I thought Configuration class can be used to specify components to scan, like  @Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "com.hello.package.p1", "com.hello.package.p2" })
public class TestConfig {
}  But you are saying configuration class itself is picked up based on component scan?

Comment: An `@Configuration` is also an `@Component` and as Spring Boot by default does scanning in the package (and the sub packages) it is defined in....